# Link a phone number to existing firebase account

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I m trying to link a phone number to an existing account for my flutter app to avoid spam account.
steps : 1. on click of register button I run `.verifyPhoneNumber()`, it must return me a `PhoneAuthCredential`. Then I get into my `signUp()` (future) function that creating a firebase account and after that links my returned `PhoneAuthCredential`.

But my problem is when I call `.verifyPhoneNumber()`, instantly my signup function is called so my `.verifyPhoneNumber()` return is null. I don't know how to wait for a non null return to get into my `signUp()` function.

Here my call when I click on register :

```
ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        controller.verifyPhoneNumberThenSignUp(
                            phoneNumberFieldController.text.trim());

                        controller.signUp(
                          firstname: firstnameFieldController.text,
                          lastname: lastnameFieldController.text,
                          email: mailFieldController.text.trim(),
                          countryCode: countryCode,
                          password: passwordFieldController.text,
                          username: usernameFieldController.text.trim(),
                          phoneNumber: phoneNumberFieldController.text.trim(),
                         
                        );
                        firstnameFieldController.clear();
                        lastnameFieldController.clear();
                        mailFieldController.clear();
                        passwordFieldController.clear();
                        usernameFieldController.clear();
                        phoneNumberFieldController.clear();

                        //Get.to(() => MailVerificationPage());
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Créer mon compte !"),
                  )
```

My verifyPhoneNumberThenSignUp :

```
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumberThenSignUp(
    String phoneNumber,
  ) async {
    phoneNumber = "MY NUMBER FOR TESTING";
    try {
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          timeout: Duration(seconds: 120),
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          // verificationCompleted only gets called when verification is doxne automatically
          verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
            phoneNumberCredential =
                credential; //public variable used to link with mailSignUp account

            Get.back();
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
            print(exception);
          },
          codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
            final _codeController = TextEditingController();
            Get.dialog(AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Give the code :"),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _codeController,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              actions: [
                CupertinoButton(
                    child: Text("Confirm"),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                          verificationId: verificationId,
                          smsCode: _codeController.text.trim());

                      UserCredential result =
                          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

                      User user = result.user;

                      if (user != null) {
                        //Get.to(NavigationThroughTheApp);
                        print("Verification completed !!");
                        print(user.phoneNumber);
                        Get.back();
                      } else {
                        print("Error on user null safety");
                      }
                    })
              ],
            ));
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {});
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", e.message, snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    }
  }
```

My signUp :

```
Future<void> signUp({
    String firstname,
    String lastname,
    String email,
    String countryCode,
    String password,
    String username,
    String phoneNumber,
  }) async {
    //if (await Database().usernameExists(username) != true) {
    //FIREBASE REGISTRATION
    //bool toto =
    //await verifBigo(); //FIXME n attend pas la verif pr continuer donc tjrs false

    // if (toto == false) {
// phone number verified
    try {
      print("checking phone credential not null...");
      if (phoneNumberCredential == null) return;
      print("phone credential not null");
      showLoading();
      //_firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted, verificationFailed: verificationFailed, codeSent: codeSent, codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout)
      UserCredential _authResult = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      print("Try linking phoneNumber to created account");
      user.linkWithCredential(phoneNumberCredential);
      print("phoneNumber linked to created account !!!!! ");
      user.sendEmailVerification();

      UserModel _user = new UserModel(
          id: _authResult.user.uid,
          firstname: firstname,
          lastname: lastname,
          email: _authResult.user.email,
          countryCode: countryCode,
          passwordHash: null,
          username: username,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          creationDate: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()));

      if (await Database().createUser(_user)) {
        print("account registred in our DB");
        if (!Get.isRegistered<UserController>()) Get.put(UserController());
        Get.find<UserController>().user = _user;
        Get.back();
      }
      Get.put(PartyController(), permanent: true);
      Get.offAll(() => NavigationThroughTheApp());
      /*} else {
      Get.snackbar(
        "Error creating Account",
        "Username already taken",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
      }*/
      // }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        "Error creating Account",
        e.message,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for asynchronous methods to complete by putting the `await` keyword in front of the method and marking the function in which you're calling the asynchronous method as `async`.

Your `onPressed` callback should be updated to this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    await controller.verifyPhoneNumberThenSignUp(
      phoneNumberFieldController.text.trim());

    await controller.signUp(
      firstname: firstnameFieldController.text,
      lastname: lastnameFieldController.text,
      email: mailFieldController.text.trim(),
      countryCode: countryCode,
      password: passwordFieldController.text,
      username: usernameFieldController.text.trim(),
      phoneNumber: phoneNumberFieldController.text.trim(),
    );

    firstnameFieldController.clear();
    lastnameFieldController.clear();
    mailFieldController.clear();
    passwordFieldController.clear();
    usernameFieldController.clear();
    phoneNumberFieldController.clear();

    //Get.to(() => MailVerificationPage());
   }
 },
```

Comment: This is what I don't understand, I already try it but it doesn't work. I just retry right now to check if it wasn't a mistake from myself but keep not working. It jump instantly in my signup function with fill my AuthCredential.

Comment: It keep doesn't work, I really don't understand what is wrong.